# Save state for multiple screens

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

TL:DR - 
How to share data(state) between controllers and services but refresh this data when switching views

---

In the current project I am working on I am having design problem.

The the website have a couple of different views but all of them share the same characteristics - table in top and more info the bottom, also they share the same base directive and data (each view deals with different aspect of the data)

I also have other services and factories that should have access to this data.

So, at first glance it looks like a service would be a good place to store the shared data for the views. However the data should be initialized when switching among the different views and that's where the singleton nature of the services is problematic.

As of now in the data service I have init function which being called in the shared directive scope destroy event, though this solution seems inadequate to me and I wanted to know if there is a better way to do this

Here is a description I made in paint of how the screen looks,
[screen example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krDXP.png)

Comment: Could you simplify the question?

Comment: How to share data(state) between controllers and services but refresh this data when switching views

Comment: You need to show some code. This question makes no sense whatsoever without code and a description of problem referencing that code

Comment: I can't share code because of some legal issues but I tried to draw how it looks in paint =/, Its the most I can do, hope it helps you understand what I want. thank you anyway

Comment: you are asking about something very specific, it's very hard to determine the problem/solution without having a look at the code that structures your "different views"